# Linked slide between Powerpoint presentations

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Is it possible to link slides in PowerPoint so that a slide is common to two presentations so when it is changed in one file, it updates also in the other one?

Another alternative that would be great is if there could be a third presentation file that would be linked in both presentations.

Comment: Depending on how you navigate the presentation, you can create a clickable link to a different presentation; when the other presentation ends or the user quits by pressing ESC, they're returned to the original page they came from and can continue navigating from there normally.

Comment: How would one link presentations as such?

Comment: Select a shape or some text (depending on what you want to make clickable), press Ctrl+K to open the insert link dialog box, choose "Existing file or web page", browse to the presentation you want to link to, select it and OK.

Comment: This doesn't really help me. I'm looking for a solution that is 'transparent' to the user. Anyway thank you for helping

Comment: Another option, then, is to start with the file you're going to change, select the slide that may change and ctrl+C to copy it.  Then switch to the presentation you want to include it in, add a blank slide, choose Paste Special, select as Powerpoint Slide and put a check next to Link.  Resize the pasted slide to fill the slide you just pasted it into.  Personally, I'd then put another rectangle above it, no line, fillled but fill set to 99% transparent.  This will "trap" users' clicks so they don't inadvertently launch the linked slide.